# nginx if not in directory

Tags: nginx

I want to create an if statement in nginx configuration that says

if location is not /images/ directory then do something.

I can do this to say if it is in the images directory but don't know how to do the opposite.

```
if location ^~ /images/ {
   do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
location / {
  # do something
}

location /images {
  # do not
}
```